# How to auto refresh Power bi reports automatically on hourly basis

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I am trying to find a solution for hourly automatic refresh for my power bi reports but without any success. One of my data source is Oracle database. Also my bi report is on Microsoft teams. So, please help me find a query in power bi which will help in hourly automatic refresh.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried setting a scheduled refresh  in the power bi service?? you'll be limited to 8 per day with a power bi pro license